# setPostedProducts with flat catalog category / product

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I'm using setPostedProducts to maintain a sale/discount category.
On my dev machine, it's working (flat catalog category and product is **off**).
On my stage machine (flat catalog category and product is **on**), it's not working anymore.

How can I fix this?

```
category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId); // category id of my sales category
$category->setPostedProducts(array(123 => 1)); // product 123 should be the only one in my sales category for testing purposes
$category->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't really know why, but what solved my problem was adding

```
Mage::app('admin');
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
```

before executing setPostedProduct().
I suppose that in admin the _getResource() function translates into Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category instead of Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category_Flat